# Is Oracle's execution plan cache tied to connection or it is a global map which is used for all connections?

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

My Java application fires a query from JDBC connection conn1 and oracle stores that query's execution plan in its cache. If same query is fired from a different JDBC connection conn2, will Oracle reuse the cached execution plan from the older query?

In other words, is the Oracle's execution plan cache global or is it created on per connection basis?

Comment: I am talking about execution plan which oracles reuses for example in case of PreparedStatements

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/memory.htm#GUID-DE757E9C-3437-408A-8598-3EB4C8E2A3B0

Comment: Thanks! this gives a good detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Instance wide. If you are using a cluster (RAC), then if your connection is to another instance, then it will not "see" the cached execution plan from the first instance.